# MongoDB: copy documents from one collection to another while adding an attribute

Tags: java, mongodb

I am looking for an efficient way to copy a number of documents from one collection to another while adding an attribute. Basically, I have a "spool space" collection where the documents pile up, and at a given time, I have to add a special metadata node and push these in the documents collection.

Limitations and environment:

- we are using the java-driver
- we do **not** know the document structure
- Mongo-Version is 3.2

Right now, we are doing it document-wise like this:

```
    spool.find(
        eq("transfernode.id", currTransferId)
    )
    .forEach((Consumer<Document>) doc -> {
        doc.append("execnode", createMarkerNode("somedata")); // creates a sub-doc
        docs.insertOne(doc);
    });
```

However, this is *very* inefficient.

The perfect thing would be to use the aggregation pipeline and add the node in the $project phase, but unfortunately you have to include a list of fields for the projection, and as I already noted, we do not have such a list as the structure is unknown (i.e. up to the user.)

(Sub-question: can the project-phase somehow be used to include *everything* without knowing how this everything looks like?)

The next experiment was using MongoDB mapReduce. Basically, this works like a breeze, but the result documents from map-reduce have the form

```
{
   _id: "anId",
   value: {
       ... (this is the document I want)
   }
}
```

(Note: I have seen the answer to the question 
  [1]: [mongoDB map/reduce minus the reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581058/mongodb-map-reduce-minus-the-reduce/3605054#3605054) but calling db.insert in the finalize function is out of question. Mongo docs state that this is to be avoided absolutely, and I want to keep the solution "clean")

Maybe there is a way to just "copy up" the value-part to new documents in a "bulk" way?

So, does anyone have an idea how to achive this?

Edit: in the original question text above, I mentioned that the aggregation pipeline seems a possible way. In the meantime I discovered, that the aggregation $out stage *replaces* a collection instead of updating it. Therefore, this cannot be used either. :-(

Comment: if _id is created by mongoDB you can get some N documents --> add filed --> save in another collection --> skip N documents limit N ....... process continues untill no documents left

Comment: No, the _id is not generated by mongo. Apart from that, the "how to save it in another collection" (without explicitly looping through the documents) is part of the question.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431773/mongodb-aggregation-project-include-all-fields-plus-new-one

Comment: Played around with that a little, but if I use $project: { custom_field: { $literal: "a value" }, document: "$$ROOT" }, my document ends up under a "document" sub-node, which basically is the same problem I have with the map-reduce-approach.